# Physionet dat file parsing trouble Matlab

Tags: matlab, dat-protocol

I am having trouble parsing a dat file in Matlab. I am getting the error:

```
Number of columns on line 2 of ASCII file ../physionetdata/set-a/a00.dat must be the same as previous lines.
```

I wanted to take a look at the data within this file but it doesn't seem like I can view it properly (it's a jumbled mess of symbols).

It should look something like this:

423.0 261.0 728.0 460.0 695.0 521.0

422.0 263.0 713.0 462.0 693.0 521.0

420.0 265.0 697.0 462.0 693.0 521.0

418.0 266.0 681.0 465.0 690.0 521.0

416.0 268.0 663.0 465.0 690.0 521.0

414.0 270.0 644.0 465.0 687.0 521.0

412.0 272.0 624.0 468.0 685.0 521.0

What can I do to view the data in a dat file? This can help me to proceed to find out how I am getting that Matlab error while processing the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert the data to ASCII format first. Then using load function in MATLAB.